# Рефакторинг вместо if else

Tags: java, рефакторинг

Как отрефакторить этот код чтобы он был более понятен и красивее, можно ли это сделать или это самый оптимальный вариант

```
AsyncResponse asyncResponse = waiters.remove(userData.getClientId());
if (userData.isManagerEntered()) {
    response[0] = getPersonEntered(userData);
    asyncResponse.resume(response[0]);
    userData.setManagerEntered(false);
} else if (userData.isMessageReceve()) {
    response[0] = getChatReceived(userData);
    asyncResponse.resume(response[0]);
} else if (userData.isDisconnected()) {
    response[0] = getCallDisconnected(userData);
    userData.setDisconnected(false);
    System.out.println("isdisconnect");
    asyncResponse.resume(response[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно добавить константы и заменить на такой вид:

```
switch (userData.status) {
    case UserData.STATUS_DISCONNECTED:
        // isDisconnected code
        break;
    case UserData.STATUS_MANAGER_ENTERED:
        // ...
        break;
    default:
        Log.d(TAG, "не обработанный статус")
}
```

`.resume()` вынести за условие

---

В конечном итоге должно выйти что-то типо этого:

```
AsyncResponse asyncResponse = waiters.remove(userData.getClientId());

switch (userData.status) {
    case UserDate.STATUS_MANAGER_ENTERED:
        response[0] = getPersonEntered(userData);
        userData.setManagerEntered(false);
        break;
    case UserData.STATUS_MESSAGE_RECEVE:
        response[0] = getChatReceived(userData);
        break;
    case UserData.STATUS_DISCONNECTED:
        response[0] = getCallDisconnected(userData);
        userData.setDisconnected(false);
        System.out.println("isdisconnect");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Untreated status: " + userData.status);
}

asyncResponse.resume(response[0]);
```

---

src/com/example/UserData

```
// public class UserData extends otherUserData {
public class UserData {
    private int _i = 0;

    static final int STATUS_DISCONNECTED = _i++;
    static final int STATUS_MANAGER_ENTERED = _i++;
    static final int STATUS_MESSAGE_RECEVE = _i++

    private int status;

    public UserData() {
        // Обработка объекта
    }
}
```

**Java** вообще такой язык, в котором без собственных классов не обойтись. **userData** судя по всему это уже какой-то класс, в котором есть статус и этот класс можно было бы расширить и создать собственный класс для удобства.

Вот я к чему.

---

```
static final enum Status { DISCONNECTED, MANAGER_ENTERED, MESSAGE_RECEVE }
```

при этом Status уже объект, а не int.

http://www.quizful.net/post/java_enums

Подробнее об enum в Java

Comment: как я добавлю константы и буду проверять через status, что вы имеете ввиду под константами

Comment: дополнил ответ.

Comment: А можно ли как то использовать enum

Comment: в JAVA enum увы нет такой как в том же самом c++. Кода выйдет больше чем я описал выше. Но как вариант... сейчас дополню код

Comment: вы имеете ввиду что код будет больше, а будет ли он более понятен для чтения

Comment: В Java __enum__ создает не __int__ переменные и потому он создается дольше, по времени, он больше памяти занимает и для обычных констант это не очень удачное решение на мой взгляд.